# How to plot a linear vector tangent to a Bézier surface?

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus, splines

I have a Bézier surface and its parameters are `u` and `v`. The partial differentiation with `u` as variable gives me a vector in the direction of `u`. I need to plot this vector.

I plugged in a particular value of `u` and `v` and got my partial derivative vector as `{0, 1, 0.7}`. How do I plot this vector on my surface as an arrow pointing in direction of `u`?

Answer (score 5):

If you give us your equation, we can plot it directly.  In the meantime...

```
myscalarField = Sin[x] - y^2 - z;
myvectorField = D[myscalarField, {{x, y, z}}];
v = VectorPlot3D[myvectorField, 
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   VectorPoints -> 25, 
   VectorScale -> {0.1, Scaled[0.5]}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, z}, -0.1 <= myscalarField <= 0.1]];
c = ContourPlot3D[
   myscalarField == 0, 
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
       Mesh -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Green]];
Show[v, c]
```

[image]

or... for a single vector:

```
myscalarField = Sin[x] - y^2 - z;
myvectorField = D[myscalarField, {{x, y, z}}];
c = ContourPlot3D[
   myscalarField == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   Mesh -> None,
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Green]];
v = Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow[{beginvec = {Sin[0], 0^2, Sin[0] - 0^2}, 
      beginvec + {.5, .5, .5}}]}];
Show[c, v]
```